# Passing partial attributes into Beautiful Soup findall Function

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm relatively new to python, but I've been following some youtube tutorials. I've been using the beautifulsoup4 library to do some data-scraping. And I want to use the findall function based on a part of one attribute.

The attribute is onclick = some_garbage-importantline-garbage. Is there a way to find an object based on a part of the attribute.

I tried to use this line of code to do the trick:

```
soup.findAll('a',{'onclick':'[^.]*importantline[^.]*'})
```

It doesn't work. I've tried looking it up, but I guess I don't really know how to phrase this question or what to look up. Please point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **you are not compiling your regular expression**. Also, you can simplify it:

```
import re

soup.findAll('a', {'onclick': re.compile(r'importantline')})
```

---

Besides, you can avoid using regular expressions and use a function:

```
soup.findAll('a', onclick=lambda x: x and 'importantline' in x)
```

Comment: I think yours deserves to be accepted answer. I also know that bs4 has a `attribselect_re` as `re` replacement

Comment: @Anzel sorry for waving in here, least I can do is to plus one your answer - since it is a valid option also. Thanks!

Comment: dont worry, better answer always deserves it ;) and I'm actually not very good at regex so yeah I learn something too

Answer (score 1):

Try using list comprehension:

```
[a for a in soup.findAll('a') \
    if a.get('onclick') and 'importantline' in a['onclick']]
```